# button ng-click is not working in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

ng-click is not working in ionic button, it's saying that in console as below

> VM67 index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: zPLysearch() is not defined

I've been trying to fix this problem for 2 hours I did't get any luck. 
Here my code,

```
<div class="col-90" >
  <button ng-click="zPLysearch()" class="button button-delete">zPLY search</button>
</div>
```

but same function using like as below It's working fine

```
<div class="homecard wired" ng-show="show2" ng-click="zPLYsearch()">
</div>
```

Here My full html code

```
<ion-view title="zPLY Conf Tool"> 
  <ion-content padding="true" class="content_background">
      <div class=" homecard wired" ng-show="show2" ng-click="zPLYsearch()">
     </div>
      <div class="col-90" >
      <button ng-click="zPLysearch()" class="button button-delete">zPLY search</button>
    </div> 
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller Code:

```
angular.module('wiredzplydetailscontroller', [])
  .controller('wiredzplydetailsCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$ionicModal,$ionicPlatform, $ionicLoading,$ionicPopup, $timeout, $location) {

$scope.zPLYsearch=function(){ 

}


});
```

Comment: Do you have a zPLysearch function defined in js file?

Comment: yeah I defined in controller.

Comment: Please check below answer and it is working for me.

Comment: yeah I agree with your answer. it's working fine outside the controller. within controller I'm using same function in div like this `<div class="row homecard wired"  ng-click="zPLYsearch()"></div>` ,It's working fine but same function I'm using as I asked question, it's not working

Comment: Can you please share you code

Comment: I think, you have to define one function in controller and another outsede of the controller to acces with onclick

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ng-click on your button like this..

`<div class="col-90" >
  <button ng-click="zPLysearch()" class="button button-delete">zPLY search</button>
</div>`

Comment: The function is different in your div code and button code, The 'Y' is uppercase and lower case.

Comment: ng-click="zPLysearch()"

ng-click="zPLYsearch()"

Answer (score 0):

```js
function zPLysearch()
{
  console.log("test");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-90" >
  <button onclick="zPLysearch()" class="button button-delete">zPLY search</button>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```